# SQL Server : I want to get the row to which this value belongs

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with multiple columns. And contains column of min value. And column the max value.

I want to get the row to which this value belongs

```
min_value  max_value  Amount
----------------------------
1            10        1000
11           20        2000
21           30        3000
31           40        4000
41           50        5000
51           60        6000
61           70        7000
71           80        8000
81           90        9000
91           100       10000
```

For example, I want to search for the number 45

I expect the output to be 5000

```
SELECT Amount 
FROM test 
WHERE min_value >= 41 AND max_value <= 50
```

This would not be helpful

Because I don't know the default values beforehand

Comment: `where val >= min_value and val <= max_value`??

Comment: This would not be helpful Because I don't know the default values beforehand

Comment: You can pass `val` through as a column or parameter, and I think you misunderstood that query please read it again. We use `val` twice, we do not need to know the min and max values beforehand

Comment: Yes, this is true. I seem to have misunderstood
Thank you this is the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is between min and max, so you can use `min <= num => max`:

```
SELECT Amount 
FROM test 
WHERE min_value <= @number and max_value >= @number
```

[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90aee/1/0)